# Superior Measure of Lebesgue

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ and $B$ are sets measurables. Prove $\mu^*(A \cup B) + \mu^*(A \cap B) \leq \mu^*(A) + \mu^*(B)$

I tried to use $A \cap B \subset A \subset A \cup B$. Similarly to $B$ and I apply the Lebesgue measure but  that doesn't work. 
Could you help me?

Comment: What is your definition of $\mu^*$?

Comment: $\mu*(A) = \sum_{A \subset \cup_{n} B_{n}} m(B_{n})$ where $B_{n}$ are elementals sets

Comment: Do you mean, the infimum over all such collections $ B_n $ containing $ A $ ?

Comment: Exactly, sorry i didn't write it

Comment: What does 'medibles' mean?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use the following properties of the Lebesgue measure and exterior measure

$$\mu^{\star}(A) = \inf_{U \text{meas}, A\subset U} \mu(U)$$

Let $\epsilon >0$.  Take $U$, $V$ measurable so that $A\subset U$, $B\subset V$ and
$$\mu(U)\le \mu^{\star}(A)+ \epsilon/2$$
$$\mu(V)\le \mu^{\star}(B)+ \epsilon/2$$
Now $ A\cup B\subset U\cup V$ and $ A\cap B\subset U\cap V $. So
$\mu^{\star}(A\cup B) \le \mu(U\cup V)$, $\mu^{\star}(A\cap B) \le \mu(U\cap V)$. Therefore
$$\mu^{\star}(A\cup B)  + \mu^{\star}(A\cap B) \le \mu(U\cup V) + \mu(U\cap V) = \mu(U) + \mu(V) \le  \mu^{\star}(A) + 
\mu^{\star}(B)+\epsilon$$